# Do gradings of representation categories come from centers of the algebra?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I'm interested in (semi-simple) representation categories of groups and Hopf algebras. These categories are monoidal and sometimes even graded-monoidal.

The way I know how to get graded-monoidal categories of representations is by having some center, since then we may grade the simple representations by the representation they carry of the center.

Are all graded representation categories formed this way? That is, can I infer something about the center if I know about gradings on the representation category?